# Find closest locations - 2 lists of latitude and longitude

Tags: excel, distance, latitude-longitude

I have two data lists, one of airports, the other of major cities. both the lists have latitude and longitude data.

How can I:

1. match the airports to their closest city
2. find the distance between the airports and their closest city

Both lists are in Excel.

Comment: I suppose you would have to resolve the position into a proper coordinate system (polar/cartesian). Then you can calculate the arc length between two points fairly easily.

Comment: What exactly is the format of the latitude/longitude cells??

Comment: Hi Gary the lat/longs are in decimals

Comment: Very good!  i would like you to review Jerry Latham's tutorial here:  http://www.contextures.com/excellatitudelongitude.html#formulas    The writeup gives the essentials that we can adapt to you schema

Comment: Thanks - We'll take a look and see if it helps! :)